# Twitter bootstrap modal via javascript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the button toggle modal format down, but what I'm trying to do is initiate the modal  via fade in when user is not logged in and clicks on a tab within the header.
Below is the code I have. It works when I put a button down but when I click the tabs  nothing is happening. What should fire the modal when clicked and user is not logged.

```php
<script type="text/javascript">


<?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']){ ?>


cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")


cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu1")

<?php } else{?>

   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal('show')  
   });
 });


 <?php } ?>

 </script>
```

```html
<div style="display:none;" class="modal hide fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

OK I managed to get it to work, forgot the data-target="#myModal" within the tabs.

Comment: I think you need to show some HTML so that we understand fully how the tabs are involved.